# I want to wait till my device gets paired completely(BLE)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on **BLE** stuff but for pairing i want to wait in same activity

Answer (score 0):

In your App. Register Broadcast Receiver for bluetooth pairing

```
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
        filter.priority = IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter)
```

inside your Receiver do your stuff

```
 mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
   //Do your Stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting this callback for BLE. After successful pairing only i have to jump to next activity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you .
I have done that using this

```
if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)){
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            //3 cases:
            //case1: bonded already
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
                startActivity(intentNewActivity);
            }
            //case2: creating a bone
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
            }
            //case3: breaking a bond
            if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
            }
        }
```